# MS Access 365 TransferSpreadsheet picks wrong row as field names for import

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I have an MS Access application that is importing data from an Excel workbook.  Both apps are Office 365.  The first row in my worksheet has the field names.  I have this statement in my MS Access VBA code:

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "XYZ", "C:\MyExcel.xlsx", True, "A1:N100"

If the table "XYZ" exists in my database and has the corresponding fields then I get an error like "No field named '12345' in table".  If the table "XYZ" doesn't exist, then I get a table with field names like "12345", "23", "45", etc.  These are the values in the 11th row of my data.

Is this a known bug, or is there something more I have to do to mark the first row as the one with the field names?  I've put in statements to select A1 or select the entire used range before executing the DoCmd, but I got the same results.  I've run the statement without the "A1:N100" and got the same result.

When I set the 'Has Headers' value to False and try to insert the data, I still get the "No field named '12345' in table" error.  It seems to ignore the 'Has Headers' value and pick one of the rows as the field names.  Is this also a known bug?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have never encountered this. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your workbook for analysis.

Comment: I just found the error.  I was trying to Transfer from an open workbook.  When I closed the workbook and then did the transfer, it worked as advertized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I was running the Transfer command against an open workbook.  When I closed the workbook and then ran the Transfer command everything worked fine.